# Regex: extracting multiple substrings, ignoring the variant matches

Tags: regex

`","(.*?) (Railway Station)`

I need to extract a station city and latitude/longitude from a list of raw data in the following format:

```
"22238","Flinders Street Railway Station (Melbourne City)","-37.8183051340585","144.966964346166"
"22239","North Melbourne Railway Station (West Melbourne)","-37.8063098353473","144.94151017321"
"22240","Footscray Railway Station (Footscray)","-37.8014134330439","144.902020057667"
"22241","Sunshine Railway Station (Sunshine)","-37.7885363319246","144.832878204953"
```

The desired output being:

`Flinders Street` `-37.8183051340585,144.966964346166`
`North Melbourne` `-37.8063098353473,144.94151017321`
`Footscray` `-37.8014134330439,144.902020057667`
`Sunshine` `-37.7885363319246,144.832878204953`

I'm after some advice on how to handle this.

Using `","(.*?) (Railway Station)` the station city is extracted, but there are two other undesired matches:

`","Flinders Street Railway Station`
`Flinders Street`
`Railway Station`

In the above, how could I solely match `Flinders Street` ?

Secondly, to retrieve the latitude and longitude, should I perform a seperate regex call, or is this all possible with a single search pattern?

And finally, should I remove the quotes from the latitude/longitude using regex or afterwards in my code, splitting the problem into two steps.

For example, from:
`"-37.8183051340585","144.966964346166"`
to:
  `-37.8183051340585,144.966964346166`

Alternatively, I'm coming at this from the wrong angle and it would be simpler to split the text with `,` as the delimiter, focusing then on the smaller substrings with a specific pattern. What are your thoughts?

Comment: What's your language? I'm not sure that using only Regex could be efficient. Your data seems to be CSV. So you may just want to iterated each line, get each components of the CSV (since they are separated with ","), and check the presence of your searched term in the second component. It would be then easier to concatenate your lat/long according to your desire format. It may be simpler to read the code in a few months.

Comment: The language is Python. Agreed, I find regex patterns basically impossible to read 5 minutes after writing them.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'","(.*?) Railway Station', input)`, or if you are using `re.search`, access the group 1 value with `matchObj.group(1)`.

Comment: Or, try [`","([^"]*) Railway Station[^"]*","([^"]+)","([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fV8yJ2/1). With `re.findall`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/0Bje8Z).

Comment: Also, does [this code](https://ideone.com/6HARK9) work for you? No regex at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
"([^"]+)\s+Railway\sStation[^,]+,"([^"]+)","([^"]+)"$
```

`\1` is `Flinders Street`, `\2` is `-37.8183051340585`, `\3` is `144.966964346166`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA3aI9/5)

Comment: Perfect, I'll make sure I understand it before I use it, thank you.

Comment: @livin_amuk No problem

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `","(.*?) (Railway Station)` matches, as you say in an example, `","Flinders Street Railway Station`. It **captures** `Flinders Street` and `Railway Station`. Note the distinction between matching and capturing. Matching is everything that the regex matches (of course). Captures are parts of the regex enclosed in `()`. Like your `(.*?)` - **and** - `(Railway Station)` giving you two capture groups.

To just match, not capture, the `Railway Station` remove the parentheses - like `","(.*?) Railway Station`. This will **match** the same thing as yours, but only **capture** the station. Then, to match without capturing the city, add `\([^)]*\)` which matches the parentheses and anything between.

Finally, adding `","([^"]*)","([^"]*)"` will capture the coordinates in two more capture groups giving the final

```
","(.*?) Railway Station \([^)]*\)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)"
```

to do the job.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uV8lW5/1).

Regards